# efcore generated postgresql update statement with sub-select doesn't seem to be running transactionally

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a command which I'm executing against a postgresql database through entity-framework-core (efcore 7). The command is intended 'claim' some record. Each record should be claimed once and ONLY once.

```sql
UPDATE command AS c
SET execution_heartbeat = @__GetTimeUtc_2,
    claim_id = @__claimId_1
FROM (
    SELECT c0.command_id, c0.active, c0.claim_id, c0.execution_heartbeat, c0.sid, c0.started_on, c0.status, c0.tenant_id
    FROM command AS c0
    WHERE c0.status = 0 AND (c0.claim_id IS NULL)
    ORDER BY c0.sid
    LIMIT @__p_0  --1 in this case
) AS t
WHERE c.command_id = t.command_id
```

This above statement is executed via the following code block

```cs
Guid claimId = Guid.NewGuid();
int affected = 0;

using (var context = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    affected = await context.MyTable
        .Where(c => c.Status == CommandStatus.QUEUED)
        .Where(c => c.ClaimId == null)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Sid)
        .Take(maxClaims)
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(
            setPropertyCalls: calls => calls
                .SetProperty(c => c.ClaimId, claimId)
                .SetProperty(c => c.ExecutionHeartbeat, TimeAccessor.GetTimeUtc()),
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    var claimedIds = await context.MyTable
        .Where(c => c.ClaimId == claimId)
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    this.Logger.LogDebug("Claiming {Count} records: {Ids} with Claim: {ClaimId}", affected, string.Join(", ", claimedIds), claimId);

    return claimedIds;
}
```

However, when there are multiple threads running this in parallel, some of the records end up getting 'claimed' multiple times. IE, have two different threads which.

- declare a unique claimId
- update some records, which should have a NULL claimId, to the new claimId
- select the records which now have my new claimId

And they both return the same id. This doesn't seem like it should be possible as I'm assuming that the update statement runs transactionally and will only update records which have not been updated previously.

I'm sure I could find a way to 'code around this'. But hoping someone could shed some light on what might be happening here, and what incorrect assumption(s) I might be making.

Comment: You're by default on [`read committed` transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). This means all concurrent transactions only know what's been *claimed* **before** their statement began. You might be interested in [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) or changing the structure so that there's a table listing who's claiming what and a `unique` constraint preventing any two claims from calling dibs on the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [explicit lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) will fix this. Unfortunately, the [EFCore issue for explicit locking](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26042) is still open, so you'll have to switch to a raw query to work around that:

```sql
UPDATE command AS c
SET execution_heartbeat = @__GetTimeUtc_2,
    claim_id = @__claimId_1
FROM (
    SELECT c0.command_id, c0.active, c0.claim_id, c0.execution_heartbeat, c0.sid, c0.started_on, c0.status, c0.tenant_id
    FROM command AS c0
    WHERE c0.status = 0 AND (c0.claim_id IS NULL)
    ORDER BY c0.sid
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED---------------------------here
    LIMIT @__p_0  --1 in this case
) AS t
WHERE c.command_id = t.command_id
```

Here's your case reproduced on 9 background workers trying to issue your original query concurrently: [demo1 at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nZjAcbwS). They all end up claiming the exact same row.

Here's another demo showing how it's fixed by adding the explicit lock: [demo2 at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eHpVZgcD). Each one got a different one, because locking made them skip the locked rows when fetching the one to claim.

---

You're by default on [`read committed` transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). This means all concurrent transactions only know what's been *claimed* **before** their statement began. You might be interested in [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) or changing the structure so that there's a table listing who's claiming what and a `unique` constraint preventing any two claims from calling dibs on the same thing.

Level `repeatable read` is actually worse, because every statement in a transaction sees the snapshot of the db from before the whole transaction, while `read committed` "refreshes" the visibility after each statement throughout the transaction.

The last one, `serializable` will cause any two concurrent conflicting transactions to just fail, and you'll have to keep catching that and retrying on your app level. It also comes with performance penalty for the db - if you run A and B at the same time, PostgreSQL has to make sure running A before B would have the same result as running B before A.